# Possible to get BodyPart.Text only from Contents on Orchard CMS?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm using ajax to get body text of a certain post type, at the moment I'm using

`/Contents/Item/Display/x`

but it shows all the html tags, is there a method/url i can call so that it only returns string of body text? Or should i make one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built in that will let you get the body text only by requesting a URL. You will need to add your own controller or do your own filtering of the returned HTML in JavaScript.